# Shibboleth - How to configure multiple Password Authentication Configurations

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, shibboleth

In shibboleth we have PasswordAuthnConfiguration.

i want to have multiple PasswordAuthnConfiguration nodes which will be chosen depending on SP.

i am able to choose an authentication method based on SP from replying party.xml
but what if i want to have multiple set of configurations for PasswordAuthnConfiguration and picking on depending on SP.

eg.,,

SP1 - PasswordConf 1

SP2 - PasswordConf 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution,
if anyone else needs the same solution.

**system/flows/authn**
duplicate the below flows with a name of your choice

> password-authn-beans.xml password-authn-flow.xml

like

> passworda-authn-beans.xml passworda-authn-flow.xml

to have separate set of datasource configurations for the new flow
edit

```
passworda-authn-beans.xml
    <import resource="../../../conf/authn/passworda-authn-config.xml" />
```

to have a seperate login page for the new flow
edit

```
passworda-authn-flow.xml
    <view-state id="DisplayUsernamePasswordPage" view="mylogin">
```

duplicate the login.vm page and personalize it.

now every authentication flow is identified by a unique name
like password based authn flow is "Password"
so we have to define a name for our new authn flow
lets call it "Mypassword"

edit the file system**/conf/webflow-config.xml**
add the below line

```
<webflow:flow-location id="authn/Mypassword" path="../system/flows/authn/mypassword-authn-flow.xml" />
```

now to setup configurations for datasource for the new authn flow

> go to conf/authn duplicate the file password-authn-config.xml to
>   mypassword-authn-config.xml

setup your datasource to configure your users datasource for authentication

enable the new flow in **conf/idp.properties**

> idp.authn.flows= Password|Mypassword

configure the new authn flow to your specific customera datasource
in

> conf/relying-party.xml

```
<bean parent="RelyingPartyByName" c:relyingPartyIds="urn_ping_saml"> 
            <property name="profileConfigurations">
                <list>
                <bean parent="Shibboleth.SSO" p:postAuthenticationFlows="attribute-release" />
                <ref bean="SAML1.AttributeQuery" />
                <ref bean="SAML1.ArtifactResolution" />
                <bean parent="SAML2.SSO" p:authenticationFlows="#{{'Mypassword'}}" p:postAuthenticationFlows="attribute-release" p:encryptAssertions="false"/>
                <ref bean="SAML2.ECP" />
                <ref bean="SAML2.Logout" />
                <ref bean="SAML2.AttributeQuery" />
                <ref bean="SAML2.ArtifactResolution" />
                <ref bean="Liberty.SSOS" />
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```